# Error When "INSERT IGNORE INTO" with OPENQUERY on Linked Server in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, linked-server

I get error when executing SQL Query below using a linked MySQL server through ODBC MySQL driver.

Here is the code ...

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO OPENQUERY (MYSQL, 'SELECT ITEM_CODE, PRODUCT, PRODUCT_DESC_1, VENDOR, SELL_QUANTITY_ORDERED, SELL_UNIT_OF_MEASURE, DATE_ORDERED, DATE_DUE, JOB_NUMBER, ITEM_ORDER, DATE_SHIP_BY FROM software_joblogportal.line_item')  
(ITEM_CODE, PRODUCT, PRODUCT_DESC_1, VENDOR, SELL_QUANTITY_ORDERED, SELL_UNIT_OF_MEASURE, DATE_ORDERED, DATE_DUE, JOB_NUMBER, ITEM_ORDER, DATE_SHIP_BY)
SELECT ITEM_CODE, PRODUCT, PRODUCT_DESC_1, VENDOR, SELL_QUANTITY_ORDERED, SELL_UNIT_OF_MEASURE, DATE_ORDERED, DATE_DUE, JOB_NUMBER, ITEM_ORDER, DATE_SHIP_BY FROM CBSPORTAL.WebCBS.dbo.Software_LINE_ITEM
```

Trying to find a way to get IGNORE INTO to work with OPENQUERY if possible.

Error: 
"Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INTO'."

Comment: IGNORE is a MySQL keyword, but you're trying to use it in T-SQL. Only what is inside the statement within the OPENQUERY will be processed on the target linked server.

Comment: As T-SQL supports comments, and [mysql reads comments](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=445) of the form `/*! comment */`, try `INSERT /*! IGNORE */ INTO ....`. I've no idea if T-SQL is going to pass this though the ODBC layer but its worth a try.

Comment: Thanks for the comment idea. I tried but it didn't work. I think I may need to go the route of replacing the data as a whole during each sync.